# graphql playground is not loading and console error

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo

I am using @nestjs/graphql as follow:

//app.module.ts

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
    driver: ApolloDriver,
    typeDefs: [my custom typedefs],
    resolvers: [my custom resolvers],                        
    introspection: true,
    installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
    dataSources: () => {
        return {
            ...
        } as DataSources<RESTDataSource>;
    }
})
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/gateway": "^2.0.0",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.5.0",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.0.19",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.1.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.0.21",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.1",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.1.4",
    "apollo-datasource-rest": "^3.4.0",
    "apollo-server": "^3.10.0",
    "applicationinsights": "^2.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "axios-request-throttle": "^1.0.0",
    "azure-devops-node-api": "^11.1.1",
    "execution-time": "^1.4.1",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "graphql-parse-resolve-info": "^4.12.0",
    "graphql-request": "^3.4.0",
    "limiter": "^2.1.0",
    "nest-neo4j": "^0.1.5",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0",
    "tedious": "^11.4.0",
    "ts-morph": "^15.1.0",
    "win-node-env": "^0.4.0",
    "winston": "^3.7.2",
    "winston-azure-application-insights": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

I have angular ui for which nestjs is backend server. After updating @nestjs/graphql from 7.x.x to 10.x.x playground is not working and getting console error as below.

```
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
    at new BrowserModule (platform-browser.js:1527:1)
    at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as factory] (platform-browser.js:1549:58)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11457:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11276:1)
    at core.js:11314:1
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:11314:1)
    at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:25345:1)
    at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:25399:1)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:3680:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:1)
    at zone.js:1278:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28679:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1)
```

Tried multiple versions of @nestjs/graphql, no luck.

Comment: In further analysis found /graphql GET is not retuning playground html instead its responding with my Single Page Application's index.html which is in client directory. I am using module from `@nestjs/serve-static` to enable my client code. Not sure why updating @nestjs/graphql causing this issue. is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to incompatible dependency version for `@nestjs/serve-static`. Fixed after bumping major version.